# Scope variable in AngularJS controller not cleared on revisiting the view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, signalr

I am writing an AngularJS client application which communicates with SignalR 2.2. The Angular application also uses Angular UI Router library.

My hub class looks like:

**MessagingHub.cs**

```
public class MessagingHub : Hub
{
    public void Connect()
    {
        Clients.Caller.connected();
    }

}
```

The main app module is given below:

**app.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

    //Global error handler for the signalR
    $.connection.hub.error(function (err) {
        console.log('An error occurred: ' + err);
    })
    //Make signalR proxy as a service available to other components.
    angular.module('app').value('message', $.connection.messagingHub);


    angular.module('app').config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        // For any unmatched url, send to /contact
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/contact");

        $stateProvider
          .state('contact', {
              url: "/contact",
              templateUrl: "/app/contact.html"
          })
            .state('messaging', {
                url: "/messaging",
                templateUrl: "/app/messaging.html"
            })

          .state('about', {
              url: "/about",
              templateUrl: "/app/about.html"
          });

    });

})();
```

*contact.html* and *about.html* files contain nothing apart from some headings.

messaging.html is given below:

**messaging.html**

```
<div ng-controller="messaging as vm">
    <h1>Messaging</h1>
    <div ng-show="vm.isConnected"><p class="label label-primary">Welcome...</p></div>
    <div ng-show="vm.isAvailable"><p class="label label-info">Your status is available now</p></div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-click="vm.onStartMessaging()">Connect</button>

</div>
```

and the corresponding controller is given below:

**messaging.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('messaging', ['$scope', '$timeout','message', messaging]);    

    function messaging($scope, $timeout, message) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.isConnected = false;
        vm.isAvailable = false;
        vm.onStartMessaging = onStartMessaging;
        message.client.connected = onConnected;

        function onStartMessaging() {
            $.connection.hub.logging = true;
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {                
                message.server.connect();
                $timeout(function () {
                    vm.isConnected = true;                    
                });
            });
        }

        function onConnected() {                            
            vm.isAvailable = true;   
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    }
})();
```

when I first go to "Messaging" view and click 'Connect' button, it calls the `Connect` function on the `Hub` which then calls `connected` function on the caller. The handler function in my Angular controller sets `vm.isAvailable = true` which in turn shows a lebel on the view.

Everything works fine but when I move to other view and come back and click the 'Connect' button again, same process goes through as mentioned above but in the `onConnected()` javascript function the value of `vm.isAvailable` is already set to `true` so the label is not displayed at all which is odd.

Can anybody help me to understand why this is happening and what options do I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem. The only thing I had to do was to handle the state change event for the ui router and close the connection with SignalR hub like below:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
    $.connection.hub.stop();
});
```

Now it really makes sense to close the hub connection when the user navigates away from the messaging view but why the `vm.isAvailable` is not set to `false` on revisiting the view if the SignalR hub connection was not closed when the user navigated away is still a mystery for me. If someone knows the answer to this and can give me some logical reason I will accept the answer.

Comment: this works, Thanks a lot. A link about the same problem: http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2014/05/30/signalr-auto-disconnect-when-page-changed-in-angularjs.aspx